# rails new project not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I cannot get the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html tutorial to work. Once I create the rails project and run rails server to see the "welcome aboard" page I get a "page does not exist" error in browser. I tried assets:precompile, however that did not work. This used to work fine but it does not anymore. 
Rails version 3.2.13

Here is the part in production.log that I think may be relevant:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
```

Comment: Do you have a default route set up? Make sure you're using `root to: "welcome#index"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you're root to route is setup in your config/routes.rb file.

Try `root to: "welcome#index"`.

Comment: Doing this does not bring up the "welcome aboard" screen. I just tried and also deleted the html files in public. There seems to be no welcome_controller.rb inside controllers. A couple of weeks ago I created a project and the welcome_controller.rb file was there. It isn't any more

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai Try undoing the generator and create it again. Use `rails d controller welcome` and then `rails generate controller welcome index`

Comment: Well this helped me get a rails page to show up on the browser. The simple Welcome#index webpage for creating a new controller. I guess it at least shows up so that's good. Thanks! I will accept it as the answer but I still don't understand why the tutorial given on their website doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add root route to `config/routes.rb` file, example:

```
root to: 'things#index'
```

in this example you would have to have `app/controllers/things_controller.rb`:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
```

and a view `app/views/things.html.erb`, could be an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

One thing they do not tell you in the tutorial is in order to see a new scaffold or view etc you will need to delete the default rails view(index.html) inside of the public folder. After you have done so make sure yours routes are correct and most importantly restart your server after doing changing route file.